# How should I edit a .bst file to output a page range, specified by Chicago Manual of Style?

Tags: chicago-style

This is my first time to use this board.

I am now modifying a .bst file, and trying to create a Chicago-like style. Look at the italicized page number, below, cited from the url at the bottom.

Reference list entry

Thoreau, Henry David. 2016. “Walking.” In The Making of the American Essay, edited by John D’Agata, *167–95*. Minneapolis: Graywolf Press.

Here, I guess the page ranges from 167 to 195, but the first digit of 195 is omitted. I have no idea how to make this output. Will you show me how I should modify the .bst file? I am modifying the LandP.bst file, linked below.

Chicago (author-date)
http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide/citation-guide-2.html

LandP.bst
http://artstein.org/resources/LandP.bst

By the way, I do know that there is Chicago.sty and Chicago.bst or something similar (Sorry, I forgot proper names of the styles). However, as far as I tried, none of them follow this funny digit omission, or some didn't properly typeset on my Mac.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Are you using the Linguistics and Philosophy `.bst` file because you're submitting to that journal or because you think it's a Chicago style?  But without a minimal document showing what you're doing and the specific `.bib` file entry that causes the problem it will be hard to help you.  See [How to write a MWEB (Minimal Working Example with Bibliography](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/2693).

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Well, I do not think that PandL.bst is a Chicago style. I am just modifying it to get an output that I want because I thought this .bst file looks similar to what I want. As for MWEB, I apologize that I did not ask a question properly. I will edit the question as soon as I can.

Comment: There is a `biblatex-chicago` style which is up-to-date and will likely implement exactly the style you want.

Comment: See [Get biblatex-chicago working](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/30288) for a working example. You should change option `notes` to `authordate` for author-date formatting.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help! I am trying to typeset my document with the biblatex-chicago style. I am having a trouble with this, so it may take a bit of time to use it properly.

Comment: Since you're using a Mac, you might want to consider TeXShop's `pdflatexmk` engine which will do all the relevant compilations for you automatically. See [can't get latexmk to work in TeXShop](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/127788)

Comment: Alan, thank you for your very quick and generous comments. It seems all the issues I had seem to be solved. Thank you!